# Creating embeddable objects in nextJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js, embed

How can I make one of my component in NextJS embeddable on other websites. I am using SQL for storing data which would be displayed in the object

Comment: did you consider using a monorepo?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just now had a look at it